# Platform specific HeightRequest

Tags: maui

I tested my .NET MAUI App on **iOS - Emulator** and **Pixel 5 - API 33 (Android 13.0 API 33)**. It seems like Android is displaying a little differently regarding how much space controls need.

Below a Frame I have a Button and it is like the space below the Button and the Frame is too small regarding what I want and how the look and feel in other Frames with Buttons is. On iOS it is looking good.

So, when increasing the HeightRequest for the Frame it doesn't look as good as before on iOS but looks good then on Android.

I could not set a platform specific HeightRequest as the compiler told it is not supported for HeightRequest.

How should I do it in XAML or is there only a way to set it in the Code-Behind then? Or are there even better ways to deal with this issue in general when switching between platforms?

Comment: [Frame](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/frame) is deprecated in MAUI, you should try the new [Border](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/border) instead.

Comment: **Show the code you are trying to fix.** Show the  Frame and Button and their parent layout. The solution wouldn't involve HeightRequest, it would involve margins. Or maybe something about the parent layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it in the xaml, such as:

```
<Frame>
   <Frame.HeightRequest>
      <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:Double">
          <On Platform="Android" Value="50"/>
          <On Platform="iOS" Value="200"/>
      </OnPlatform>
   </Frame.HeightRequest>
</Frame>
```

Comment: Yes, for Label.HeightRequest it is possible but not for a Frame, obviously. Do you have an idea for the Frame?

Comment: I changed the Label in the code above to Frame and it also worked. And The official document said : **The Frame class existed in Xamarin.Forms and is present in .NET MAUI for users who are migrating their apps from Xamarin.Forms to .NET MAUI. If you're building a new .NET MAUI app it's recommended to use Border instead, and to set shadows using the Shadow bindable property on VisualElement.** So you can use the border instead of the frame. @OXO

Comment: Could you please show the code about setting a platform specific HeightRequest in your project? @OXO

Comment: I can try again and replace my Frame by a Border instead, but this didn’t work out very well when I tried it in the first place. Anyway, is there a way so that I don’t need to set a HeightRequest at all and the Boder/Frame expands based on its content? I don’t like these HeightRequests anyway as I permanently have in mind „oh how will it be displayed on another display size or platform?“.

Comment: Border (and Frame) do expand with their content. Set HeightRequest on the content, not the Border.

Comment: Okay, I switched to Border as you recommended. I also could get rid of the HeightRequest and worked with a Margin. The former Frame and now the Border has a StackLayout inside, the other one a Grid and both can work with a Margin, so I could get rid of setting absolute Heights - Thanks guys